# Why Ubuntu 12.10 the touch screen inputs goes to second monitor?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, touchscreen, dualhead, xinput

I have Elo touch screen, connected to a VGA output, and i have another screen connected to HDMI output.

When i touch the Touch screen, its 1024x768 resolution, the cursor goes always to other screen when i drag my touch it moves on other screen abnormally. How do i tell all the touch input should stay in touch screen not in other screen? I have tried:

```
xinput set-int-prop "Elo TouchSystems, Inc. Elo TouchSystems 2700 IntelliTouch(r) USB Touchmonitor Interface" "Evdev Axis Calibration" 32 -4000 4093 -100 4089
```

But its not working at all. Any fix on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for Dual screen: left 720p right 1024x768

```
  left:                                right:
[ 1280/(1280+2560)  0          0 ]   [ 2560/(1280+2560)  0          1280/(1280+2560)]
[ 0                 1024/1440  0 ]   [ 0                 1440/1440  0               ]
[ 0                 0          1 ]   [ 0                 0          1               ]

$ xinput set-prop "Elo TouchSystems, Inc. Elo TouchSystems 2700 IntelliTouch(r) USB Touchmonitor Interface" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.8659999 0 0.55555555 0 1 0 -0.04 0 1

> almost correct
0.8659999 0  0.55555555 0  1.09 0  -0.04 0  1.000099
c0        c1 c2         c3 c4   c5 c6    c7 c8
```

> How do i invert the cursor?

```
xinput set-prop "Elo TouchSystems, Inc. Elo TouchSystems 2700 IntelliTouch(r) USB Touchmonitor Interface" --type=int --format=8 "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0, 1
                                                                     X, Y = 0 false , 1 true
```